# Representing object for a functor mapping a category to composable morphisms

Tags: category-theory, functors, morphism, natural-transformations, hom-functor

If I have a functor $D_n : \mathsf{Cat} \to \mathsf{Set}$ that maps a category into the set of all $n$-tuples of composable morphisms,
$D_n(C) = A_1 \to A_2 \to A_3 \to \dots \to A_n$, what would its representing object be?

I have a gut feeling it would be a category with a single object and $n$ endomorphisms? But I also thought of it being a thin ordered set with $n$ objects. Either way, I don't know how to proceed or how I would prove it once I find an answer.

Comment: Hint : The functor $\mathcal{Cat}\rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$ mapping a small category $\mathcal{C}$ into the set of morphims of $\mathcal{C}$, is represented by the category $0\rightarrow 1$ with two objects and a single morphims between them.

Comment: Given a candidate object for representing the functor, what would you need to show? In other words, what diagram would you need to verify?

Comment: That the commuting square commutes XD? So if we have a natural transformation $\alpha : D_n(C) \rightarrow Hom(X,C)$, and a functor $f : C \rightarrow D$, then we will also have   $D_n(D) \rightarrow Hom(X,D)$ and the square will commute

Answer (score 1):

Consider the category $1\xrightarrow{t_1} 2\rightarrow\dots\xrightarrow{t_{n-1}} n$ with $n$ objects and $n-1$ composable morphisms.
We want to show that there exist a natural bijection $D_n(\mathcal{C})\cong Hom_{\mathcal{Cat}}(1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n,\mathcal{C})$ for any category $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $\textbf{A} \ : \ A_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} A_2 \rightarrow\dots \xrightarrow{f_{n-1}} A_n$ be an $n$-tuple of composable morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$. Consider the functor $F_\textbf{A}$ from the indexed category $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n$ to $\mathcal{C}$, defined on objects as $i\mapsto A_i$, and on morphisms as $t_i \mapsto f_i$ for any $i=1,\dots,n-1$.
One can show that the function $D_n(\mathcal{C})\rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{Cat}}(1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n,\mathcal{C})$ sending an $n$-tuple $\textbf{A}$ of composable morphisms to the functor $F_\textbf{A}$ defined before, is a bijection.

Moreover, given a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$, the following diagrams commutes
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D_n(\mathcal{C}) @> >> Hom_{\mathcal{Cat}}(1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n,\mathcal{C})\\
@V {D_n(F)} VV @VV {F {\circ} -} V \\
D_n(\mathcal{D}) @> >> Hom_{\mathcal{Cat}}(1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n,\mathcal{D})\\
\end{CD}
$$
Thus, we've showed the bijection $D_n(\mathcal{C})\cong Hom_{\mathcal{Cat}}(1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n,\mathcal{C})$ is natural, and so the functor $D_n$ is represented by the category $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow n.$

Comment: Could we not map it to a category with a single object and n endomorphisms?

Comment: @noCrayCray Let's suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a category with a single object and $n$ endomorphims. How would you define a function $D_n(\mathcal{C})\rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{Cat}}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{C})$ for any small category $\mathcal{C}$? In any case, you don't get a bijection.